# Is API key needed when making a request for Google Directions and Geocode?

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I'm developing an application for both Android and iOS which is using Google Maps API, Google Directions API and Google Geocode API. The maps can't run without the API key so I got one from Google Console. There are API keys for Directions and Geocode too but I haven't requested them. In the documentations for Geocode and Directions it's written that API key should be added in the URL request and I haven't added them when I request from them and it is still working perfectly.
My question is: Do I need to request API keys for them? The app will be commercialized in the future.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#api_key

> All Directions API applications should use an API key.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem - Here Google says that the keys are just recommended.

Comment: 'The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 and the Maps Image APIs previously did not require an API console key. This is still supported for legacy applications to ensure backwards compatibility, but is no longer recommended for new applications.' - I think this isn't true when we talk about Android, because they want to limit max requests to 2500 / day when you are using free version.